# ANTLR list separated by whitespace

Tags: parsing, antlr

I'm a new ANTLR user and I'm trying to parse a text, where numbers are separated by whitespace:

> 1 2 3

My grammar consists of these rules:

```
program : expr+ ;
expr : vector ;
vector : INTEGER+ ;
INTEGER : [0-9]+ ;
WS : [ \t] -> skip ;
```

With this, text is parsed correctly but reporting ambiguity. How can I resolve the ambiguity for this rule?

Comment: I have updated my post with entire grammar

Comment: How do you know if `1 2 3` is `[1 2 3]` or `[1] [2 3]` or `[1] [2] [3]` or `[1 2] [3]`

Comment: I understand the problem, the text 1 2 3 should be parsed like [1 2 3]. How can i define the rule to have this behaviour

Comment: I already use ANTLR 4.8 and the string is parsed correctly but ANTLR with DiagnosticErrorListener and prediction mode set to PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION return me ambiguity problem. It's possible to resolve this problem?

Comment: @mirkomario: get rid of `expr`. If you always want the longest possible `vector`, there can only be one `vector` and `expr+` is pointless. Alternatively, use some punctuation (semicolons, newlines, something) to separate `expr`s, thereby allowing your program to have more than one of them.

Comment: Please add the ambiquity warning you get in your question. I don't see any ambiquity in this grammar.